# Prepare docker installation for "offline" environment

Tags: redhat, docker, docker-compose, offline-files

We're going to deploy our codebase in an environment with no outbound internet access - using docker. However - we do not seem to be able to pre-build the entire thing so we don't have to pull images from any repository.
The server is prepared with docker and docker-compose.

We have a `docker-compose.yml` file, its a lot longer that this but this is the part that we don't get to work:

```
 node:
    container_name: my-node
    build: ./docker/node
    volumes_from:
      - volumes_source
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
```

In /docker/node we have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

EXPOSE 5000

RUN npm install pm2 -g

CMD ["pm2-docker", "/var/www/laravel/socket/socket.js"]
```

I want to pre-build this so that it wont have to run the `npm install pm2 -g` bit - since it wont work. What I have tried is:

1. Booted this as a container on a internet connected host
2. `docker commit 8671bf3bd1b5 my-node:latest` (8671bf3bd1b5 is container id)
3. `docker save -o my-node.docker my-node:latest`
4. `docker export 8671bf3bd1b5 > my-node_latest.tar`
5. Transfered files to offline environment
6. `docker load -i my-node.docker`
7. `cat my-node_latest.tar | docker import - my-node:latest`
8. Remove `build: ./docker/node` from docker-compose.yml in offline environment and replace with `image: my-node:latest`

It still tries to pull node:latest and run `npm install pm2 -g` though. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you have exported image/container named my-node:latest. But in Dockerfile, it is built from node:latest, which you forget to export. ...